# Use SSIS to get measures from a tabular model

Tags: ssis-2016

I need to get source data from an Azure Analysis Services via SSIS. While I can easily use an OLE DB source in SSIS to fetch columns from tables, I do not see measures listed.

Is there a way to get values from measures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the value of a measure without an evaluation context. You can however execute a DAX query to fetch the data that you need. Once you have defined your connection manager, instead of choosing `Table or View` as your data access mode, choose `SQL Command`. You can then specify the DAX Query which will evaluate the measure within your defined context. After you have defined your query you can click on the **Preview** button to see the data that will be returned.

You can find a step by step guide on how to do this [here](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s2481/dax-query-ssis.htm).

Comment: The step by step guide you provided is exactly what I need and I was having a hard time on Google trying to find anything remotely similar. Thanks!